# problema al descargar imagenes con selenium en python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

Tengo un problema cuando descargo una imagen cuando uso selenium en python.
Quiero descargar una imagen de la web https://www.webdeejemplo.com a la cual tras acceder a dicha web logueandome con selenium hago los clicks necesarios para poder llegar hasta la imagen en cuestion.
Cuando quiero bajar la imagen hago lo siguiente

```
imagenadescargar = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#contenedor_grafica > p > img")
src = imagenadescargar.get_attribute('src')
time.sleep(5)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, "C:\\todo\\1.png")
```

Esto hace que se baje el archvo 1.png al directorio c:\todo, pero cuando quiero abrir el fichero 1.png me aparece un mensaje que dice "1.png Parece que el formato de este archivo no es compatible".
Decido no rendirme y me descargo a mano la web en local, reescribo el codigo y cambio el driver para aplicar selenium a ese html local dejando el resto del codigo igual y para mi sorpresa en local si que funciona, logrando que el 1.png se guarde correctamente.

cuando trabajo sobre el html en local uso:   driver.get('file:///C:/todo/prueba.html')
cuando trabajo sobre el html de la web uso:  driver.get('https://www.webdeejemplo.com')

Para la descarga estoy usando las librerias requests  y urllib
No entiendo que puede estar pasando, por que funciona en local y no funciona cuando lo hago a la web de internet.

Comment: No sé mucho de Python, pero si algo de selenium. Podrías hacerte 2 preguntas: ¿La URL devuelta es correcta? ¿Estás seguro de que la imagen se encuentra en el formato que la estás guardando (.png)?

Comment: Hola!  si si, la imagen si se encuentra en png.      Respesto a la pregunta de si  la url devuelta es correcta,  no se a que te refieres, que quieres decir exactamente?

Comment: Me refiero a si la URL es la misma que obtienes manualmente de la página.

Comment: La pagina original de internet tiene la url https://www.webdeejemplo.com  mientras que al descargar en local esa pagina, en mi navegador tiene la url file:///C:/todo/prueba.html

Comment: Si estás seguro de que todo lo que haces está bien, otra posible causa es que el servidor te este bloqueando. Intenta lo que sugiere la respuesta a esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50758637/ulrlib-downloading-image-unsupported-format

Comment: ok lo probare.  muchas racias.